# Apply all modifiers, .poll() a bpy operator with keyword argument?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I would like to apply all modifiers to an object with python.

```
for mod in ob.modifiers:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = mod.name)
```

This works fine, unless for some reason the modifier is disabled, e.g.:

- A Boolean modifier with no object
- A Shrinkwrap modifier with no target

General Problem:

Other than knowing all of the possible attributes of every modifier and checking to make sure the modifier is valid, is there a way to `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply.poll()` while specifying which modifier I want to apply?

I see that the `poll()` method expects

`poll(self, *args)`.

Perhaps I can put something in for `*args` which will help

Work Around: I can get the modified mesh `object.to_mesh()`

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is **no**, `poll` checks that the basic context is valid but it doesn't do extensive checks that every operation will succeed *(It's often not trivial for tools to know this ahead of time)*

You can simply use exception handling for this.

```
for mod in ob.modifiers:
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        # print the error incase its important... but continue
        print(ex)
```

---

In this case I think you would be better off using,

- `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')` - converting a mesh to a mesh will replace the mesh with a version that has modifiers applied.
- `Object.to_mesh()` - gives you most control, uses Pythons internal API.

Comment: just wanted to follow up that to_mesh works fine for this!  Thanks

Comment: @patmo141 If this answer was helpful you should mark it as 'accepted'. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers