# A comprehensive list of operator overrides

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I feel like I'm always spending far too much time playing scripting whack-a-mole whenever I want to [override an operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) in one of my scripts. **I'd like to build a comprehensive one-stop-shop list for the most used operator overrides**.

Comment: Since [Blender 3.2](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Python_API) passing the context to operators as a dictionary has been deprecated as part of the inclusion of `Context.temp_override` which should be used instead.

Answer (score 11):

| Operator | Required context members | Q&A's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`ed.lib_id_generate_preview()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ed.html#bpy.ops.ed.lib_id_generate_preview) | `id` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245447/) |
| [`ed.lib_id_load_custom_preview()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ed.html#bpy.ops.ed.lib_id_load_custom_preview) | `id` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245447/) |
| [`file.execute()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.file.html#bpy.ops.file.execute) | `window` - [`Window`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCache.html#bpy.types.PointCache) reference `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference |  |
| [`fluid.bake_data()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.fluid.html#bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data) | `scene` - [`Scene`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference `active_object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188255/) |
| [`image.save_sequence()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.image.html#bpy.ops.image.save_sequence) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237312/) |
| [`info.report_copy()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html#bpy.ops.info.report_copy) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference |  |
| [`info.select_all()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html#bpy.ops.info.select_all) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference |  |
| [`mesh.customdata_custom_` `splitnormals_clear()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear) | `mesh` - [`Mesh`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference |  |
| [`object.delete()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.delete) | `selected_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27235/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35038/) |
| [`object.duplicates_make_real()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real) | `selected_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references |  |
| [`object.geometry_nodes_input_` `attribute_toggle()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.geometry_nodes_input_attribute_toggle) | `object` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references |  |
| [`object.make_single_user()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.make_single_user) | `selected_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references |  |
| [`object.material_slot_remove()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7164/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146719/), [#3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202038/) |
| [`object.modifier_apply()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference `view_layer` - [`Viewlayer`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCache.html#bpy.types.PointCache) reference (Optional) `scene` - [`Scene`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference (Optional) | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219782/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44509/), [#3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133136/), [#4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7706/), [#5](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314555) |
| [`object.modifier_copy_` `to_selected()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference `selected_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243753/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292607/) |
| [`object.modifier_move_down()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175862/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249694/), [#3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98900/) |
| [`object.modifier_move_to_index()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_to_index) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference |  |
| [`object.modifier_move_up()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175862/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249694/), [#3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98900/) |
| [`object.object.join()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.join) | `active_object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13986/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135893/) |
| [`object.origin_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.origin_set) | `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186009/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214714/) |
| [`object.parent_clear()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.parent_clear) | `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references |  |
| [`object.parent_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.parent_set) | `object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references |  |
| [`object.posemode_toggle()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle) | `active_object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference |  |
| [`object.select_all()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.select_all) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCache.html#bpy.types.PointCache) reference |  |
| [`object.shade_smooth()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth) | `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278145/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274331/) |
| [`object.transform_apply()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.transform_apply) | `selected_editable_objects` - Sequence of [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) references | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175325/) |
| [`palette.extract_from_image()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.palette.html#bpy.ops.palette.extract_from_image) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCache.html#bpy.types.PointCache) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/247799/) |
| [`ptcache.bake()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ptcache.html#bpy.ops.ptcache.bake) | `scene` - [`Scene`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference `active_object` - [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) reference `pointcache` - [`Pointcache`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCache.html#bpy.types.PointCache) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277408/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35624/), [#3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6252/), [#4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234023/), [#5](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6747/) |
| [`render.opengl()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.opengl) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220055/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135995/) |
| [`screen.area_close()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_close) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273278/) |
| [`screen.area_dupli()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175818/) |
| [`screen.area_split()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_split) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214877/) |
| [`script.execute_preset()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.script.html#bpy.ops.script.execute_preset) | `window` - [`Window`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293493/) |
| [`sequencer.sound_strip_add()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/302186/) |
| [`text.reload()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.text.html#bpy.ops.text.reload) | `edit_text` - [`Text`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference |  |
| [`text.run_script()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.text.html#bpy.ops.text.run_script) | `edit_text` - [`Text`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273500/) |
| [`view3d.view_axis()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference `region` - [`Region`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149838/) |
| [`view3d.walk`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.walk) | `area` - [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) reference `region` - [`Region`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html) reference | [#1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230836/), [#2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214412/) |
| [`workspace.delete()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.workspace.html#bpy.ops.workspace.delete) | `workspace` - [`Workspace`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WorkSpace.html) reference |  |

**Notes**

- For a few operators, e.g. `object.modifier_*()`, additional parameters must be passed (in this case the name of the modifier), see the documentation of the respective operator for reference.
- The context members of [`bpy.ops.object.convert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.convert) cannot be overwritten, see [T93188](https://developer.blender.org/T93188).

---

#### Appendix

In Blender 3.2, a dedicated [context manager](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override) has been added to the Python API. Note that the [example given in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) can be simplified to:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

objs = list(context.scene.objects)
with context.temp_override(selected_objects=objs):
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

If you'd like to pass additional arguments, see the following example for reference:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        with context.temp_override(area=area):
            bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT', write_still=True)
        break
```

*For versions prior to Blender 3.2, you always had to pass the context members to each operator as a dictionary, please see the [revisions of this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/248275/revisions) for reference.*

---

#### Background

Most of the usual suggestions involve overwriting `area`, `screen`, `space` or `window` which is very cumbersome and prevents headless usage of operators, as these members are not required in many cases. To determine the required members, it is unfortunately necessary to either [take a look at the source code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/247799/86891) and deduce them from the way they are coded internally (whether in C or Python) or by manual testing the most likely possibilities.

If you'd like to contribute to this answer, please [download this blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/q3O3nVpy/), add the operator you tested and its context members to the `DataJson` text-block and run `GenerateMarkdown`, which will generate the markdown table above from scratch.

---

Comment: have you asked about this in devtalk?  perhaps someone has a script that they can run over the source to generate such a table.

Comment: That's a great idea ! I'll make sure to ask there, although I think since there are quite intricate dependencies and edge cases it might be a bit hard to get a reliable table.

Comment: @Gorgious Good initiative! Too bad that the only two upvotes are mine from a month ago... I'd propose linking the Q&A's as well. What do you think? I would take care of it, if there is some time next week.

Comment: @p2or Yeah I think all the efforts we make in this direction will bear fruits in the long run even if it is not payed in upvotes !! Thanks for the interest :)

Comment: @Gorgious how about `bpy.ops.uv.smart_project`? it doesn't work with `selected_objects` or `selected_editable_objects`. i can't tell it which objects are selected using: `with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_objects=selected_objects):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()`. i have to manually select the objects with a for loop before executing `smart_project`

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie you can try either `context.object` or `context.active_object` ?

Comment: Hi @Gorgious Sorry for my heavy delay :D ... I tried to make a [table out of your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bUHv.png) and tested how to provide links to the manual and the Q&A's as well. IMHO this makes it easier to read, but I imagine that this makes maintenance of this answer even more complicated. After a few tests, I guess that's the best we can get [out of markdown](https://gist.github.com/p2or/435a7551550e6bad8cfb5edbf731f830) What do you think? Cheers!

Comment: @p2or you can get a hell lot more if you use mathjax, but mathjax is not so portable...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you, great idea! Tried it immediately, but unfortunately mathjax doesn't necessarily [make it more readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzOHS.png). Also it seems there is no way highlighting the code properly and setting up the links. Do you have more experience with this than I do?

Comment: @p2or I have some experience with mathjax, keep in mind both markdown and mathjax will render differently on BSE and on github, also some people might read the content without e.g. javascript and they might see quirky syntax instead of readable plain text...

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady. Bummer, if javasript is a requirement to render properly, I'd go for the table, if that is even an option for Gorgious. Otherwise we will drive away people we actually want to help. Do you agree?

Comment: @p2or I once explored the idea of using a table but without a dedicated editor I found it very cumbersome. If you want to modify the answer, go for it I don't mind, on the contrary ! I just don't understand the Q&A's column, could you elaborate on its purpose ? Anyways I've made it a community wiki so anyone can chime in. If it renders badly we can always rollback. Cheers

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for your feedback. As mentioned in my first comment, I would personally find it useful to provide links to the answers already given. Don't you? ... as the links to the Q&A's would take up quite a lot of space, I have tried to shorten them. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: @p2or ah, right I understand, yes it would be a nice reference indeed !

Comment: @Gorgious Cool, done! In its full glory [it would look like this](https://gist.github.com/p2or/435a7551550e6bad8cfb5edbf731f830). Did I forget something? Re maintenance: The table is generated from a [json file within this blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5j6nKpWm/). I first tried to work with a [spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tULvj.png), but that quickly became illegible so I decided to write a quick and dirty script that generates the table for us. When you run 'Generate-Markdown' a new text block called '_Markdown' is created which you can copy and paste here. What do you think?

Comment: @p2or Nice ! Yeah go for it :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm still working on my script that helps me to detect what elements a context override requires, but I guess I might as well share it now and update it later...

### Making context copy

First, prepare a situation, in which an operator works. If you can simply run it from a console, then you can type:

```py
c = {k:v for k, v in C.copy().items() if v is not None}
```

This makes a copy of a current context, as well as removes empty (`None`) values for readability. Theoretically a context could require some value to be in the context (override) and be `None`, but I just assume this is not the case.

If you can't make he operator work from console, perhaps you can do this little trick, that changes area type, and then makes context copy, and changes it back:

```py
C.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'; c = {k:v for k, v in C.copy().items() if v is not None};
```

(you can add `; C.area.type = 'CONSOLE'` after, but you can also just press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to return to the console)

(typing `C.area.type = 0` will error with a list of available area types)

If your valid context appears in more exotic circumstances: a timer, msgbus/draw/property callback, an operator or whatever else - you can just save the context copy assigned to some type (I recommend any **except** `bpy.types.Context`), for example:

```py
bpy.types.WindowManager.context_copy = C.copy()
```

### Context Override Checker:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D, context as C

log_path = "E:/log.txt"


'''
Usage:
    
c = {k:v for k, v in C.copy().items() if v is not None}
D.texts['Text'].as_module().test(c)
'''


def log(text):
    with open(file=log_path, mode="a") as f:
        f.write(text)


def test(context_override):
    cpy = context_override.copy()
    
    # overriding those 3 keys with `None` tends to crash Blender, so I just skip checking those
    cpy.pop('scene')
    cpy.pop('view_layer')
    cpy.pop('blend_data')
    
    # you can skip removing those keys if you know they're needed
    skip = [
        'object',
        'selected_objects'
    ]
    to_remove = {k:v for k,v in cpy.items() if k not in skip}
    
    for k, v in to_remove.items():
        #prepare the environment here...
        log(k)
        cpy[k] = None  # override context value with None
        try:
            '''
                IMPORTANT!
                REMEMBER TO PASS CONTEXT OVERRIDE TO THE OPERATOR
                                 |
                                 |
            '''  #               |
                 #               v
            result = bpy.ops...(cpy, arguments...)            
            C.view_layer.update()
            if ... : # find a way to check if the operator failed
                log(f"  {result=}")
                raise ValueError
            else:
                log(" - success\n")
                # now undo all changes a successful operator has caused
                C.view_layer.update()
        except ValueError:
            log(" - ERROR\n") 
            cpy[k] = v  # restore required value
            
        # perhaps some cleanup regardless of the operator's success or failure
    
    what_is_left = {k:v for k,v in cpy.items() if v is not None}
    log(f"\n\n\n{what_is_left}") # show what's left in the context override
```

**Then in console:**

```py
D.texts['Text'].as_module().test(c)
```

### Example

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D, context as C

log_path = "E:/log.txt"


def log(text):
    with open(file=log_path, mode="a") as f:
        f.write(text)


def test(context_override):
    cpy = context_override.copy()
    cpy.pop('scene')
    cpy.pop('view_layer')
    cpy.pop('blend_data')
    
    skip = [
#        'object',
#        'selected_objects'
    ]
    to_remove = {k:v for k,v in cpy.items() if k not in skip}
    
    for k, v in to_remove.items():
        #prepare the environment here...
        cube = D.objects['Cube']
        log(k)
        cpy[k] = None  # override context value with None
        try:
            cube.location = 0,0,0
            result = bpy.ops.transform.translate(cpy, value=(0, 3, 0))     
            C.view_layer.update()
            if cube.location.y < 1:  # should be 3
                log(f"  {result=}")
                raise ValueError
            else:
                log(" - success\n")
                # no need to undo anything here, as the location is set to 0 after `try`
        except ValueError:
            log(" - ERROR\n") 
            cpy[k] = v  # restore required value
    
    what_is_left = {k:v for k,v in cpy.items() if v is not None}
    log(f"\n\n\n{what_is_left}") # show what's left in the context override
```

Then in console:

```py
>>> c = {k:v for k, v in C.copy().items() if v is not None}
>>> D.texts['Text'].as_module().test(c)
```

### Resulting log.txt file

```
active_object - success
active_operator - success
area - success
asset_library_ref - success
collection - success
editable_objects - success
engine - success
evaluated_depsgraph_get - success
layer_collection - success
mode - success
object - success
objects_in_mode - success
objects_in_mode_unique_data - success
preferences - success
region - success
screen - success
selectable_objects - success
selected_editable_objects - success
selected_editable_sequences - success
selected_objects  result={'CANCELLED'} - ERROR
selected_sequences - success
sequences - success
space_data - success
tool_settings - success
visible_objects - success
window - success
window_manager - success
workspace - success



{'selected_objects': [bpy.data.objects['Cube']]}
```

Comment: Ooh nice I do like the bulldozer approach, test every possible combination and selectively remove keys. Smart ! Would need another recursion of tests I guess if there are more than one mandatory key, like `bpy.ops.object.join` which might send the computation through the roof but I like the approach. Thankfully there aren't that many. Cheers

Comment: @Gorgious the assumption is that breaking any link breaks the chain, i.e. if an operator uses multiple values, not providing any will fail the operator. But indeed I find it quite likely an operator might use one value and fall back to another if it's not provided, in which case perhaps the script could try again in reversed order? 