bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append RuntimeError context is incorrect when called from SimpleOperator template
repro:

Run Blender 4.2.0
File -> New -> General
Scripting Workspace
Template -> Simple Operator

replace main function with
def main(context):
    bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(text="hello world", type="OUTPUT")

Blender generates a runtime error because object.
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/operator_simple.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "./blender-4.2.0-linux-x64/4.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/operator_simple.py", line 18, in execute
  File "/operator_simple.py", line 5, in main
  File "./blender-4.2.0-linux-x64/4.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Location: ./blender-4.2.0-linux-x64/4.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:109


What context needs to be setup?
in blender 3.x i would specify an override for window, screen, area
override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(overide, text='hello world', type="OUTPUT")

but in blender4, i cannot seem to specify these, either as args (no accepted), kwargs (ignored), or bpy.context (refused mutation, read only). i suppose there are other, less accessible ways to change the window, screen, and area.
might be looking into a temporary change current window

overriding the context of a bpy operator changed, there is now bpy.context.temp_override in blender 4.2+ specifically for changing the window, screen, and area context items.
for example, to bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append to all consoles currently layed out in blender:
import bpy
with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            for line in str(data).splitlines():
                with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
                    bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(text='hello world', type="OUTPUT")


see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273474/how-to-override-context-to-launch-ops-commands-in-text-editor-3-2
