# Set shade smooth with a script

Tags: scripting

I want to  shade smooth an object by its name ('Cube' for example). This is how I would do it but it doesnt work.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object['A'].shade_smooth()
```

Comment: Hello ! I suggest you study a bit how operators work and are called with the python API, there are a few examples in the python templates available from the text editor in Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blender 3.2 + :**

```
with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_editable_objects=[bpy.data.objects["A"]]):
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

**Previous versions :**

`bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth({"selected_editable_objects": [bpy.data.objects["A"]]})`

- Note the argument must be a list or at least an iterable of mesh objects.
- For a more comprehensive list of operator overrides, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/86891