# Join objects that share location

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to make a script that works kind of the same as `Merge by Distance` but to be used in Object mode. Basically, what I am trying to do is **join all the objects that have their origin at the same location**. This is the script I tried to use :

```
import bpy;

visible_objects=[ob for ob in bpy.context.view_layer.objects if ob.visible_get()];
#get all the visible objects in a list

for o in visible_objects: #iterate the objects
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active= o; #set the current one as active
    for j in visible_objects: #iterate again
        if j== o:
            continue;
        if j.location== o.location: #join the objects sharing location with the current one
            j.select_set(True);
            bpy.ops.object.join();
```

There are 2 problems with this code.

The first one is a logical one, once an object is joined to another, it "disappears" but the `visible_objects` list is still referencing it so I get the obvious error : `"ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed"`.

The second problem is that I keep receiving the warning `"Warning: Active object is not a selected mesh"` after each join even though I already set an object as active with `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active= o` and all the other objects are meshes.

Is there a way to get rid of the warning and how do I fix the algorithm so that the inexistant objects are not anymore referenced by the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bpy

dic_obj_loc = {ob : tuple(ob.location) for ob in bpy.context.view_layer.objects if ob.visible_get() and ob.type == 'MESH'}

# get same location dict
rev_multidict = {}
for k, v in dic_obj_loc.items():
    rev_multidict.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)

for k, objs in rev_multidict.items():
    print(k, objs)
    print()
    if len(objs) == 1: continue
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    for obj in objs:
        obj.select_set(True)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain what this line does tho? `rev_multidict.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)`. I know it adds `k` to `rev_multidict` but I don't understrand what `setdefault(v, set())` does.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka it's better to use `defaultdict` instead, `setdefault` reads a value from a dictionary. If no value is found, it sets the value to the - in this case - `set()`, then it reads the value again, so now it has either a reference to the new set just created, or a reference to a set that was already there.

Comment: also, vectors have a method `to_tuple` - I don't know if it's faster, but should be otherwise there's no reason for it to be there 

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My blender froze after I tried the script tho :'D

Comment: So it seems like Blender is still processing the script now, I just checked system console and the prints are still going on but the main UI turned unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks for the answers again. The script has done running, it took around 13 minutes to process 9600 objects :D

Comment: I think you can remove one step from your algorithm. `from collections import defaultdict; dic = defaultdict(set); for obj in bpy.data.objects: dic[obj.location.to_tuple()].add(obj)` then `for objects in dic.values(): ...`

Answer (score 5):

Another solution which uses a context override which will prevent blender from freezing too much because the selection states takes a lot of time to process when there are a lot of objects in the scene :

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(set)
for obj in bpy.data.objects: 
    dic[obj.location.to_tuple()].add(obj)
    
for objects in dic.values():
    if len(objects) <= 1:
        continue
    objects = list(objects)
    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        active_object=objects[0], 
        selected_editable_objects=objects
    ):
        bpy.ops.object.join()
```

[Link to the operator override arguments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides)