# Active object is not a selected mesh. temp_override is invalid?

Tags: python, scripting

**blender-3.4.1**

```py
import bpy

objs = [obj.name for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.visible_get()]

print(objs)

active_object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
selected_objects = [
    active_object, 
    bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
    ]  
with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=active_object, selected_objects=selected_objects):
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

output:

```
['Cube', 'Cube.001']
Warning: Active object is not a selected mesh
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: it should be `selected_editable_objects`, not `selected_objects` see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides

Answer (score 1):

Simply assigning the selected objects to variable `selected_objects` doesn't mean you can join them. They have to be actually selected for `bpy.ops.object.join()` to work. Here's the script that will work:

```
import bpy

objs = [obj.name for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.visible_get()]

print(objs)

active_object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
selected_objects = [
    active_object, 
    bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
]

with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=active_object, selected_objects=selected_objects):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for obj in selected_objects:
        obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: But why is a `temp_override` function needed? It also works without :  `with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=active_object, selected_objects=selected_objects):`

Comment: ah forgot to test it without. well even better if it works without. please edit and remove hehe

Comment: @XY found out from Gorgious its faster to use `with` but it should be `selected_editable_objects` https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275070/142292