# How can I use a variable for the object of bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()?

Tags: python, objects, transforms, selection-tools

I'm trying to save an object as a reference so I can repeated apply the transform when I need to, but I can't seem to save it in a variable, like I would normally try to:

```
import bpy
from math import radians

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add()
solid = bpy.context.active_object
solid.rotation_euler[2] = radians(90)

solid.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False) #this is the error line
```

The error I get is the classic
`AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'transform_apply'`

Has anyone come across a way to save the object so I can use it without repeatedly highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an [operator override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context). Assuming you're using a Blender version > 3.2.

```
import bpy
from math import radians

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add()
solid = bpy.context.active_object
solid.rotation_euler[2] = radians(90)

with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_editable_objects=[solid]):
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
```

See [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/248274/86891) for a semi-comprehensive list of operator overrides.

Comment: Awesome, that's done it. Thanks!