# Issue with simple operator for purge all material slots

Tags: python

I have issue with this line of code.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.collections['Import'].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)   
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

The code its working fine when I executed.

But after I made simple operator and button for this operation.
And when I linked this code with button.
I get this alert 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'active_material_index' Full code bellow.
I will be very grateful for helping resolving this issue

```
import collections
import bpy


#### IMPORT HANDLE ####
def Button_01(context):
    
    scene=bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].name     
    ### SET ACTIVE COLLECTION###
    collections = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children

    for collection in collections:
         if collection.name == "Import":
            bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = collection

    folder = Path(r"D:\import")
    fbx_files = [f for f in folder.glob("**/*.fbx")]
    for fbx_file in fbx_files:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=str(fbx_file))
        print('HANDLE IMPORT')
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.name.lower().startswith(""):
            print("found")
            for child in obj.children:
                print(child.name)
            
        ###### CLEAR PARENTS ######
    for obj in bpy.data.collections['Import'].all_objects:
            obj.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')
                
              
        ####  DELETED UN USED PARTS ###  ### ONLY FOR MESH BASED NAME ####
            collection_name = "Import"
            collection = bpy.data.collections[collection_name]
            meshes = set()

    for obj in [o for o in collection.objects if o.type == 'EMPTY']:
        meshes.add( obj.data )
        bpy.data.objects.remove( obj )
            

    def mesh_delete(name):
        for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            if obj.name.startswith(f'{name}'):
                obj.select_set(True)
                bpy.data.objects.remove( obj ) 
                       
    mesh_delete('screwHead')
    mesh_delete('washer')
                
             

            
    ### NAME CHANGING FROM SKU CODE TO MATERIAL ###  ### ONLY FOR SKU CODE BASED NAME ###     
       
    def Change_name(old_name, new_name):
        for obj in bpy.data.collections['Import'].all_objects:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            if obj.name.lower().startswith(old_name.lower()) :
                objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
                objName = f'{old_name}'
                obj.name = f'{new_name}'
                
    ### PURE MATERIAL SLOTS ###  
    for obj in bpy.data.collections['Import'].all_objects:
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()            
                 

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Import Handle"


    def execute(self, context):
        Button_01(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
   
  
   
    
#### MENU ####

class LayoutDemoPanel2(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "DC Render Menu- Handle"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout2"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
            
        # Big button
        layout.label(text="Import Handle:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.0
        row.operator("object.simple_operator", icon ="GHOST_ENABLED")               



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
  
       
            

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think you want `o.type != 'EMPTY'` instead of `o.type == 'EMPTY'`, `obj.data` is `None`  for empty objects. Or even `o.type == 'MESH'` since you seem to want only mesh objects

Comment: @Gorgious -- I love that this forum is the equivalent of walking down the hall at work to ask an expert!  You guys are *so* appreciated!

Comment: Hello thanks for help.
but still have this issue
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'active_material_index'

even if Im using this
`
collection_name = "Import"
collection = bpy.data.collections[collection_name]

for obj in [o for o in collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']: 
      obj.select_set(True)
      bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
      bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
      bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
`
But if you execute this code without simple operator its working fine :(

Comment: @james_t hehe thanks :) I suggest you use an [override](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides) for this. remove `obj.select_set(True) bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` and instead use :  `obj.active_material_index = 0` and `bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': obj})`

Comment: Hello I found this parts of code. and when I added it before my script this fix my issue.
```
# Set the area to the outliner
    
    area = bpy.context.area
    old_type = area.type 
    area.type = 'OUTLINER'

    ids = bpy.context.selected_ids
```
and I had to put this after my code 
```
    # Reset the area 
    area.type = old_type 
```