# How can I apply a preset to an operator and execute it using Python?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I want to use Python to run an add-on

Something like:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.export_mesh.paper_model()
```

But I need to change some settings before I run the add-on. I don't mind whether the settings are changed individually like this

```
import bpy
op = bpy.context.active_operator

op.page_size_preset = 'A3'
op.scale = 25.0

bpy.ops.export_mesh.paper_model()
```

or I call upon an existing preset like this:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.script.execute_preset(filepath="/Users/paulmmxx/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/scripts/presets/operator/export_mesh.paper_model/psg3.py", menu_idname="WM_MT_operator_presets")

bpy.ops.export_mesh.paper_model()
```

Neither of these guesses worked because the settings were not changed.

Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing three things :

- [Invoking the operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#invoke-function) instead of executing it - This will open the popup window
- Order of execution - Invoke the operator, restore the preset, execute the operator
- [Context override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override) - The operator must be made aware of the window that just popped up

```
import bpy

preset_path = "/Users/paulmmxx/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/scripts/presets/operator/export_mesh.paper_model/psg3.py"

def preset_and_run():
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        if screen.name == "temp":
            with bpy.context.temp_override(window=window, area=screen.areas[0]):
                bpy.ops.script.execute_preset(filepath=preset_path, menu_idname="WM_MT_operator_presets")
                bpy.ops.file.execute()
    
bpy.ops.export_mesh.paper_model("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
bpy.app.timers.register(preset_and_run, first_interval=0.1)
```

We use an [Application Timer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html#run-a-function-in-x-seconds) to add a small delay otherwise the popup window isn't yet registered.

I'll link [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides) for completeness about operator overrides.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gorgious That script works perfectly and the links to other things were very useful. I found the Application timer very interesting and have used it for some simulations.

The instructions say, “...avoid comments like thanks”, so I will just post this and then soon delete it.