# Multithreading in Blender Python API

Tags: python, operator

I am trying to make a script that uses a new thread in python to not make blender freeze up.

To start a new thread, I use the python threading module. It seems to work because I can create and delete objects. However, when I try to do booleans, it doesn't work because the context is incorrect. This is my code:

```
boolean = object1.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN", name="something")
boolean.object = object2
boolean.operation = 'UNION'  
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["one"]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="something")
```

I know that this code works when I don't run it in a new thread, but when I try it in a new thread, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Any ideas?

I tried the following, but got the same error:

```
with bpy.context.temp_override( selected_objects=[bpy.data.objects["one"]]):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="something")
```

Is there a better way to override the context, or some other work around to make boolean operations work? I am using blender 3.3. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. The correct override for `object.modifier_apply` is `object`, not `selected_objects`. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/86891 which means you can't batch-apply a modifier to several objects. You'll have to use a for loop. Alternatively if you don't mind applying all modifiers you can use `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')` which supports execution on multiple objects