# Boolean raise ValueError

Tags: python, modifiers, add-on, error, boolean-modifier

A boolean modifier that was working is now throwing an error in Blender 4.0.1

`raise ValueError("1-2 args execution context is supported")`

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['resX']
context = bpy.context
        scene = context.scene
        resX = scene.objects.get("resX")
        resCut = scene.objects.get("resCut")
        if resX and resCut:
            bool = resX.modifiers.new(name='bool', type='BOOLEAN')
            bool.object = resCut
            bool.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
                    {"object": resX},
                    modifier=bool.name)
```

Error throws at the 3rd from last line:  bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply

So the boolean is activated, set to Difference, but throws an error during the apply function from what I can tell. I cannot as of yet look into this via the Blender documentation due to the servers being down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A comprehensive list of operator overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to override context here: `{"object": resX}` in bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()

Operator only needs the active object (with modifier) as set in line 1

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['resX']
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
resX = scene.objects.get("resX")
resCut = scene.objects.get("resCut")
if resX and resCut:
    bool = resX.modifiers.new(name='bool', type='BOOLEAN')
    bool.object = resCut
    bool.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bool.name)
```