# Joining objects with bpy.ops.object.join doesn't respect selection state

Tags: python, blenderkit

Where is there an issue with my code? I want to merge the models under the empty object into one object and save it under each empty object, but after I run the code, it merges all the models into one model

[image]
[image]

```
import bpy
import time

class MergeTestModelsOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.merge_test_models_operator"
    bl_label = "Merge Test Models"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def mergemodel(self, mergeobj):

        # Merge other models into new objects
        for obj in mergeobj.children:
            if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj:
                obj.select_set(True)
                bpy.ops.object.join()
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.name = mergeobj.name.replace("_MODEL", "")
                bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

    def execute(self, context):
        # Obtain all models in the scene
        objects = bpy.data.objects
        
        start = time.perf_counter()
        
        for obj in objects:
            if obj.type == 'EMPTY' and obj.name.find("_MODEL")!=-1:
                self.mergemodel(obj)
                # self.report({'INFO'}, f"EMPTY: {obj.name}.")
                continue
            
        end = time.perf_counter()
        runTime = end - start
        runTime_ms = runTime * 1000
        
        print(f"Time: {runTime}\n Time_ms: {runTime_ms}")
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Time: {runTime}\n Time_ms: {runTime_ms}")

        # Display successful prompt information
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Test models merged and deleted successfully.")

        return{'FINISHED'}

class MergeTestModelsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Merge Test Models Panel"
    bl_idname = "PT_MergeTestModelsPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Add a button that will call the Merge Test Models Operator operator when clicked
        layout.operator("object.merge_test_models_operator")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MergeTestModelsOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MergeTestModelsPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MergeTestModelsOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MergeTestModelsPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi. Please use proper code tags when posting code, so the code is well format and readable for any visitor

Comment: Hello. `if obj.name.find("_MODEL")!=-1` =>> `if "_MODEL" in obj.name` :)

Comment: I modified my code, saved these models in the dictionary, and then looped through the dictionary to merge objects. However, after merging the models under one sub object, I canceled the selection of the merged object, （bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.select_set(False)）but the program no longer merged other objects. After commenting on this code, it merged all objects again. May I ask why this is   @Gorgious

Comment: I don't understand why you need to mess with selection state. I suggested a solution with an operator override where you don't need it at all

Answer (score 2):

I think it's caused by selection state not being reset after each iteration. You select objects but don't unselect the previous ones. So the last empty children get joined with the previous ones.

You can either play with the selection state or use a [context override](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/248274/86891) which is IMO more suited and will work both for `object.join` and `object.transform_apply`.

```
import bpy

def mergemodel(self, mergeobj, context):
    objects_to_merge = [o for o in mergeobj.children if o.type == "MESH"]
    if len(objects_to_merge) < 2:
        return
    with context.temp_override(active_object=objects_to_merge[0], selected_editable_objects=objects_to_merge):
        bpy.ops.object.join()
        objects_to_merge[0].name = mergeobj.name.replace("_MODEL", "")
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

def execute(self, context):
    objects = bpy.context.scene.objects    
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == 'EMPTY' and "_MODEL" in obj.name:
            self.mergemodel(obj, context)
```

Comment: mergedir = {}
for obj in objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj:
        if obj.parent.name not in mergedir:
            mergedir[obj.parent.name] = []
            mergedir[obj.parent.name].append(obj)
        else:
            mergedir[obj.parent.name].append(obj)

for key in mergedir.keys():
    for value in mergedir[key]:
        value.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.join()
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.name = key.replace("_MODEL", "")
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

Comment: I can merge the models according to the rules using your method, but as the number of models increases, running the blender code will crash. Is this due to an issue with the blender program?

Comment: @MA__AM hello, please edit the question to add the relevant code, as it stands it's hard to know what you're trying to do.It is most certainly not an issue with the program but with your script :)

Comment: btw `mergedir = {obj.name: obj.children for obj in objects}` and `for parent_name, children in mergedir.items():`. I suggest you take a crash course on python programming to help you write code more efficiently :)