Python: Randomly selecting 1 object in a set
I have a set up like this:

Where there are 3 or sometimes more grids of different objects one behind the other. The objects are regularly spaced around 20 units in each axis, tho their origins are not always at a regular point. I need to select an even amount of objects from each of the grids so that I can merge them into a single grid with all the types of objects.
I have these code from another question I made that creates 20x20x80 cells and merges the objects inside of them:
import bpy

# grid layout in space
cell_offset = (-10, -40, -10)
cell_size = (20, 80, 20)

# little helper to snap values to a grid
def snap(val, step):
    return (val//step) * step

objects = bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects # take from a collection
#objects = bpy.context.selected_objects  # or take selected objects

cells = {}
for obj in objects:
    # snap the object's location to the next lower cell corner
    key = (
        snap(obj.location.x - cell_offset[0], cell_size[0]),
        snap(obj.location.y - cell_offset[1], cell_size[1]),
        snap(obj.location.z - cell_offset[2], cell_size[2])
    )
    # group objects with the same cell
    if key not in cells:
        cells[key] = [obj]
    else:
        cells[key].append(obj)

# select all objects in one cell and join them
for value in cells.values():
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    if len(value) > 1: # joining makes sense
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = value[0]
        for obj in value:
            obj.select_set(True)

        bpy.ops.object.join()
        
        


        
        

Is there a way to tell it to select 1 of the objects in each cell at random instead of merging them?
I assume the code would help but if it has to be done differently that's also fine.


At a brief glance, I think all you need to do is delete the join line, and add an if statement with a random chance to the selector line. Python has a built in random module, try ‘if random.randrange(2):’

from random import choiceat the top of your file then after bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') simply use choice(value).select_set(True). Btw value is not the best variable name in this case, I would set it to objects or sth like that

Also BTW I don't know where you took that code from but FYI every line in the last for loop can be removed if you use an operator override. eg for objects in cells.values(): with bpy.context.temp_override(object=objects[0], selected_editable_objects = objects): bpy.ops.object.join() see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides

@TheLabCat it says random is not defined as a value. Importing Random doesn't help either since it says it doesn't have a range attribute. Wouldn't this just select an object 33% of the time and not check if something else has been selected in the cell?

@Gorgious That works, thanks

@Cornivius I did not say random.range, I said random.randrange. Nor did I say random was a built in function, but a built in module, which you seem to have guessed. It’s one thing to not pay attention to what I said, it’s another to blame me for your misreading it instead of checking your work.

@Gorgious Your combined comments appear to be an answer. Please post them as such.

Notwithstanding the first part of your script which is irrelevant to your actual question, you can select a random item from a sequence with the standard random.choice function that comes with the python standard random module. This is arguably not really a Blender question but rather a Python question, but here goes :
import random

# The first part of your script...

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for objects in cells.values():
    random.choice(objects).select_set(True)

